# Ignore acronyms as spelling errors in TeX files

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, spell-checking

My LaTeX files contain lots of acronyms and they are often highlighted as spelling errors. I tried to ignore acronyms by adding

```
syn match AcronymNoSpell '\<\(\u\|\d\)\{3,}s\?\>' contains=@NoSpell
```

(as suggested [here](http://www.panozzaj.com/blog/2016/03/21/ignore-urls-and-acroynms-while-spell-checking-vim/)) to my `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` file but the acronyms are still highlighted. I'm wondering if I'm leaving out a setting or if the settings are being overwritten by something else?

Thanks for any help!

My `.vimrc` file:

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

" Enable backspace to work like normal text editors
set backspace=indent,eol,start

" vim-latex-live-preview settings
let g:livepreview_previewer = 'open -a Skim'

" Enable Spell Checking
set spelllang=en
set spell
```

Comment: Idk how to ignore them, but you could always add them to your dictionary (`zg`, i think)

Comment: I would add all those acronyms to a project specific spell file. Following plugin helps you with that https://github.com/dbmrq/vim-dialect.